# Replace specific characters between brackets in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
str = "'${1:textbox}',[${2:x},${3:y},${4:w},${5:h}]"
```

and I would like to replace all `,` between `[` and `]` with a single space.

I have attempted to use something like

```
str.gsub!(/(?<=\[)\,*?(?=\])/," ")
```

without success.  However, if I replace `\,` in my expression with `.`, I get the expected output:

```
str.gsub!(/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/," ")

== "'${1:textbox}',[  ]"
```

Could someone please explain the proper regex technique to use in this situation, and perhaps also explain why the examples I have posted above have failed and succeeded?

I am using `ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]`

Comment: Is what you say is the expected output really the expected output?

Comment: Be careful if your string can contain nested brackets. A solution that works with no nested brackets may not work with nesting.

Comment: I agree with @sawa. Using `.` removes more than just the commas. You should use Xavier Holt's solution.

Comment: @sawa, I just responded, but it didn't show up.  Anyway, I think I should have been more clear.  When I said "expected output", I was referring to the expected output using the `.` character, not the output I was actually looking for.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be possible to do this with a single regex, but even if it is, I can guarantee it'll be ugly beyond description.  It's a lot simpler to use "nested" substitution - use one gsub to find bracketed substrings, and then use another to swap out the commas:

```
str.gsub(/\[.*?\]/) do |substr|
    substr.gsub(',', ' ')
end
```

I'm afraid I can't explain why your attempts have failed - neither of them would run for me (ruby 1.8.7 / irb 0.9.5).  IRB gave errors that vaguely said "Bad regexp syntax."  And I can't quite grok how they're supposed to work (edit: mu is too short has an awesome breakdown in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325962/589985) - check that out).  Hope this is helpful anyway!

Comment: You're probably running into troubles with the look-ahead and look-behinds (`(?=` and `(?<=`).

Comment: @muistooshort - Yup.  It could handle lookahead just fine, but choked on lookbehind.  Guess that's a Ruby 1.9 thing.

Comment: @XavierHolt, thank you very much for this solution.  It appears to do just what I needed and was much simpler than looping through the string, which what I was doing prior to attempting something more elegant.  I've never done nested subs; thanks for the nice technique.  Accepted.

Answer (score 5):

This regex:

```
/(?<=\[)\,*?(?=\])/
```

is looking for an opening bracket followed by a sequence of commas (of any length) followed by a closing bracket. That means things like this:

```
[]
[,]
[,,,,,,,,,,,]
```

Your string doesn't look like that so your first `gsub!` doesn't do anything. If you do this:

```
'[,,,,,,]'.gsub(/(?<=\[),*?(?=\])/, " ")
```

You'll get a `'[ ]'` for your troubles.

Your second regex:

```
/(?<=\[).*?(?=\])/
```

works because `.*?` matches anything (subject to newlines and `/m` and `/s` modifiers of course) and the portion of your string between `[` and `]` certainly qualifies as *anything*.

If you're trying to produce this:

```
"'${1:textbox}',[${2:x} ${3:y} ${4:w} ${5:h}]"
```

then I'd go with [Xavier Holt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325855/479863) nested `gsub` approach, that's simple and clean.

Comment: thank you very much for the breakdown.  Very nicely explained!!  Voted up.